# Couple questions about rerolls

Tags: robinson-crusoe

So the Cook has the ability called Scrounger that in the rules states:

> **Scrounger**: Discard 2 Determination tokens to reroll any gray Action
>   die. Note! You cannot use the Determination tokens gained from an
>   unsuccessful die roll to reroll that die which gave you those
>   Determination tokens.

So this brings two questions to mind for me:

1) Can the cook use his ability to reroll a gray die that was rolled by another player or can that only be on his rolls?

2) Since it says "*Note! You cannot use the determination tokens gained from an unsuccessful die roll to reroll that die which gave you those determination tokens*", does that mean if you already have 2 tokens you can gain the two from the unsuccessful roll and the 2 you already had to then reroll the die? Which would leave you at 2 tokens and the rerolling the die. This seems to me to be not the case but had a friend saying the logic was there. However it seems to me there is not a downside to rolling unsuccessful the first time provided you have 2 tokens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As stated by the rules, the "re-roll" ability may be only applied to the player using it. http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1043001/players-reroll-abilities

2) When you re-roll the dice you completely ignore any previous beneficial results from the re-rolled die. **But** you may use these 2 tokens received from the "success" die to re-roll the "wound" or "card" die. http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1098036/do-you-get-keep-determination-tokens-if-you-reroll

Comment: Thank for the links I forgot to go check out boardgamegeek lots of good info there